# CSS selector hide and show depending hover effect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to hide one DOM element with CSS (by hovering on its sibling) but it is not working correctly.

In the `.cta_call` class I have hover effect to change the `background-color`but it is needed to hide the element `.cta_telf` when the user does that interaction.

Here one example:

```css
.cta {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: -30px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
}
.cta_telf{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 22px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1984;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:red;
    position: sticky;
    text-align: center;
}

.cta_call{
    border: solid 2px red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1985;
}

.cta_call:hover {
 background-color: red;
 color:white
}
.cta_call:hover ~ .cta_telf{
 visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<p class="cta_telf">xxxxxx</p>
<p class="cta_call">¿HABLAMOS?</p>
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` selector targets *subsequent* siblings in the markup. You cannot target an element's previous sibling with CSS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector).

However, you could change the order of the markup and then use `position`, `float`, `display:grid`, or similar to move them visually.

An example using `position:absolute`:

```css
.cta {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:1em; /* Space for absolute .cta_telf */
}
.cta_telf {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1984;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:red;
    text-align: center;
}
.cta_call {
    border: solid 2px red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1985;
}

.cta_call:hover {
 background-color: red;
 color:white
}
.cta_call:hover ~ .cta_telf {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta">
    <p class="cta_call">¿HABLAMOS?</p>
    <p class="cta_telf">xxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know now, `~` will only target sibling elements *after* the current one in the HTML flow. There is no CSS selector to target an element's previous sibling.

Anyway, I suggest you to reorder your elements in the HTML, and use `display: flex`. That way, you can use the `order` property to achieve what you want. (The `order` property make it crystal clear to understand!)

Working snippet:

```css
.cta {
  display: flex;           /* Added */
  flex-direction: column;  /* Added */
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
}

.cta_telf {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 22px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1984;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  text-align: center;
  order: 1; /* Added */
}

.cta_call {
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1985;
  order: 2; /* Added */
}

.cta_call:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white
}

.cta_call:hover~.cta_telf {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="cta"><!-- Added -->
  <!-- Changed order below -->
  <p class="cta_call">¿HABLAMOS?</p>
  <p class="cta_telf">xxxxxx</p>
</div>
```